# Use java class in Graal.js

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, graalvm

Using Graal.js, how can I import a java class to script within JS?

The following code works with Nashorn JJS, but does not work with Graal.js because there is no `Java.type()` in graal, do I need to invoke truffle at some point?

```
var ArrayList = Java.type("java.util.ArrayList");
var myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("hello");
myList.add("world");
print(myList);
```

EDIT: I was able to get it to import java types using the `--jvm` paramter, which seems to indicate that it runs it on the JVM.  So does this completely pas over the GraalVM and just use the JVM?

Comment: When you use `--jvm` you are still running with Graal.js. It's a mode where you run Graal.js inside the JVM which gives you access to all the JVM features. The default mode (`--native`) runs in a pre-compiled native binary that is faster to start-up but does not support loading Java classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the --jvm arg to the JS command to run Graal.js on JVM, this will allow access to Java objects.