# How can I use custom java type in Graal.js

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

I have stored a Phone class in a java file and add it to a Static Web project `IntelliJ` idea. In addition, I created App.js file in the project and tried to call pure `node js` function under GraalVM using: graalvm/.../node -jvm -polyglot ~/source/graalvm_samples/graal_vm_sample_js/app.js but **nodejs** under GraalVM fails with the following error:  "Access to host class Phone is not allowed or does not exist."

App.js

## javascript mixin with JavaCode

```
console.log("Hello NodeJs");

var Phone = Java.type('graalSample.Phone');

let phone = new Phone(12345);

console.log(phone.number);

console.log(phone.call('Someone'));
```

Phone class:

```
package graalSample;

   public class Phone {
    
        public final int number;
    
        public Phone(int number){
    
            this.number = number;
        }
    
        public void call(String name){
    
            System.out.printf("Calling ... "+name);
        }
    }
```

Sametime, the following code with standard java types works fine.
Borrowed from here [Use java class in Graal.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725902/use-java-class-in-graal-js)

## App.js

```
 var ArrayList = Java.type("java.util.ArrayList");

 var myList = new ArrayList();

 myList.add("hello");

 myList.add("world");

 print(myList);
```

Comment: Isn't it --jvm and --polyglot? Moreover you need to add the Java class to the class path using --jvm.cp

Comment: All listed options are needed. Thank you for last one "--jvm.cp"
https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/JavaInterop.md#classpath. 
In addition, I had to build java classes before a run.

Comment: The --polyglot could be skipped in my solution due to use of JS and Java only.
Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As turned out, I have missed --jvm.cp parameter and didn't build myClass.java ahead of **node** run. 
So, here is a working solution. 
files in the directory:

```
./src/graalSample/Phone.java
./src/App.js
```

The source question had an error in package name either. The package had to be renamed from **graal_vm_sample_js**  to **graalSample**.

Before running of App.js file, I ran

```
javac -d ./out/production/graal_vm_sample_js/ ./src/graal/Phone.java
```

As a result, the class file was created and became available for the Graal.

```
node --jvm --jvm.cp="/Users/myuser/source/graalvm_samples/graal_vm_sample_js/out/production/graal_vm_sample_js" /Users/myuser/source/graalvm_samples/graal_vm_sample_js/out/production/graal_vm_sample_js/App.js
```

The output looks like

```
12345
Calling ...someone
```